# Please consider committing to the Language Learners proposal

Tags: discussion

There is a Language Learners proposal. This proposal is focused on how to learn a language effectively and is therefore also of interest to learners of the English language. Hence I decided to post it here, so that it gets the last bit of intention it needs to reach private beta.

I hope that this post is considered on-topic here.

Please consider committing through the following link:

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Language Learning]

Comment: I suggested it for our community promotion ads: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/2888/ and I've seen it pop up a couple of times already. I hope it's helping to generate some interest.

Comment: Dang, I have no idea when I've committed to that proposal. Must be only the last ice age.